# Azure Computer Vision Rotating the image By 180 degrees

Tags: azure, computer-vision

I have this attached image that I'm using the [azure computer vision read API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-2-preview-2/operations/5d986960601faab4bf452005) to read the data from. But looks like Computer vision is rotating the image 180 degrees and reading the data in this image. How can I tell Read Api not to rotate the image?  You can test it on their website here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/#features

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Read API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/upgrade-api-versions#api-response-json) detects the orientation directly, the API in your workflow returns the orientation.

[image]